# Wordpress permalink strange behavior: output depends on <div>

Tags: php, wordpress, post, while-loop, permalinks

This is really strange. the_permalink(); works well into the wordpress loop (Code below). it outputs the right URL- but for some reason in the same loop, without changing query etc, the permalink only outputs the first post.

Here is the code:

```
<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>//This outputs **right** - http://domain.de/?p=18
<?php echo $link;?>


<span class="share_overlay">
<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>//This outputs **wrong** - http://domain.de/?p=18
<?php echo $link;?>
```

So what am I doing wrong? There is nothing between... even if I only echo -> the Permalink into .share_overlay I got the same result. Without echo - same result. writing the_permalink outside of .share_overlay - the link is alright.

There is no code - no little piece of code into the function.php - even no JS running that manipulates the DOM.

Here is a bit more of my code, so that if I have n error you can punch my head on the foot ;)
$link was only to see if the result is the same. I can't see an error themes very strange to me.

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $link = get_permalink($post);?>

        <article class="post">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <em class="meta">
                <span class="icn time" title="Datum"></span><time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d') ?>"><?php the_date(); ?></time>
                |
                <span class="icn cat" title="Kategorie"></span><span class="categorie">
                <?php the_category(' '); ?>
                </span>
                |
                <span class="icn social" title="Teilen"></span><span class="share">Teilen

                        <?php echo the_permalink(); ?>//right
                        <?php echo $link;?>//right


                    <span class="share_overlay">
                        <?php echo the_permalink(); ?>//wrong
                        <?php echo $link;?>//wrong

                        <strong>Teile diesen Inhalt auf:</strong>
                        <span class="share_content">
                                <a class="t" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=&text=<?php echo $link; ?>: &hashtags=<?php if(has_tag()){$posttags = get_the_tags();if($posttags){foreach($posttags as $tag){ echo $tag->name . ',';}echo'design';}}?>">Tweet</a>


                                <a class="g" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo $link; ?>">Google+</a>
                                <a class="f" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $link; ?>">Facebook</a>
                        </span>
                        <span class="close"></span>
                    </span>





                </span>
            </em>

            <?php echo the_permalink(); ?>//right again?!
                        <?php echo $link;?>//right again?!


            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a class="more" title="weiter lesen" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </article>

        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
            <article class="post">
                <h3>No entries found here so far.</h3>
                <p>No results found.</p>
            </article>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's the problem? That the_permalink outputs both times the same url?

Comment: @Tomás Cot

The problem is that the_permalink does **not** outputs the same URL.

in <span class="share_overlay">
the output is always the first post. (?p=1)
Outside of the span it is the regular post from the while loop (example ?p=22)

Any idea?

Comment: You shouldn't be echoing the permalink, try that, but I'm not sure it's going to change anything.

Comment: @TomásCot : yep you are right, usually I do not- If I "un"echo it nothing changes.

Comment: **solved** It was not a problem of wordpress itself I think.. set wp_reset_query before the loop -> everything works now. I think I have got something messed up before so I have to look after. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

solved It was not a problem of wordpress itself I think.. set wp_reset_query before the loop -> everything works now. I think I have got something messed up before so I have to look after. Thanks for the comments –